# how to add for loop to following JavaScript to validate inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

this is my javascript which works for single input fields but I want it to work for multiple input.

here if I try to insert value for **input** **class=adv**  more than fixed **input** value of **class=full** it won't allow

```js
var $full = $('[class=full]');
var $adv = $('[class=adv]');

$adv.on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  var fullPay = parseInt($full.val(), 10);
  var advPay = parseInt($adv.val(), 10); //tell the parser it is base 10

  if (advPay > fullPay &&
    e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
    &&
    e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $adv.val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="full" class="full" value="5">
<input type="number" name="adv" class="adv" />
```

Comment: any help apriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effective line:

```
$('[class=full]').val()
```

will only take the first element with class "full".

You need to use relative DOM navigation inside the handler, eg:

```
$(this).prev().val()
```

Similar for `$adv.val()`, use `$(this).val()` and `$(this).val('')` to clear the current input.

You can also use `input` event which will catch more events, such as paste with the mouse.

```js
$('[class=adv]').on('input', function(e) {
  var fullPay = parseInt($(this).prev().val(), 10);
  var advPay = parseInt($(this).val(), 10); 

  if (advPay > fullPay &&
    e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
    &&
    e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="full" class="full" value="5">
<input type="number" name="adv" class="adv" />
<br/>
<input type="number" name="full" class="full" value="55">
<input type="number" name="adv" class="adv" />
<br/>
<input type="number" name="full" class="full" value="555">
<input type="number" name="adv" class="adv" />
```

---

Using `.next()` or `.prev()` will mean your html is brittle (any minor changes will break the js) - a better solution would be to wrap each pair:

```js
$('[class=adv]').on('input', function(e) {

  var fullPay = parseInt($(this).closest(".inputgroup").find(".full").val(), 10);
  var advPay = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);

  if (advPay > fullPay 
    && e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
    && e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```css
.inputgroup { padding:5px 0 5px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='inputgroup'>
  <input type="number" name="full" class="full" value="5">
  <input type="number" name="adv" class="adv" />
</div>

<div class='inputgroup'>
  <input type="number" name="full" class="full" value="55">
  <input type="number" name="adv" class="adv" />
</div>

<div class='inputgroup'>
  <input type="number" name="full" class="full" value="555">
  <input type="number" name="adv" class="adv" />
</div>
```

Comment: @freedomm-m thanks for the answer it is the best solution but does it have limits

Comment: Yes, using `.next()` / `.prev()` will mean your html is brittle (any minor changes will break the js).  It would be better to wrap each full/adv pair in another container div and use `.closest(".parent").find(".full")`, but I wanted to keep the html as close as it was in the original.